# 1 second video stream latency occurred with Emgu CV

Tags: c#, video-streaming, emgucv

I have a sight line decoder device connected to my PC via Ethernet.

I used Emgucv to capture the video stream and view it in an image box.

Here is part of the code:

```
 _capture = new Capture("udp://@169.254.1.144:15004");
 _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;

 Image<Bgr, Byte> frame,frame1;

 private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
 {
     frame = _capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();
     pictureBox1.Image = frame.ToBitmap();
 }
```

The video viewed in the `Imagebox`, but with 1 sec latency; I counted the frame reached  the `ProcessFramefunction` and its 12fps and its correct;

Does the `ImageGrabbed` event cause this latency?

Why does the latency occur?

Note : I used an usb camera instead the sightline and worked fine; also the sightline plus which can play the camera via Ethernet works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the length of the default buffer used by the 'Capture' object. Raw OpenCV has a 'CV_CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE' flag you can set to alter this value using .set()

Comment: thank you ,
CV_CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE only supported by DC1394 v 2.x backend currently
so how can i replace it